Generating a single result set from multiple tables dynamically in Snowflake
I am trying to get a result set with 2 columns from snowflake using dynamic SQL, this is read from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLES metadata.
I simply want the (TABLE_NAME, PUB_DATE) columns for all tables in the Schema, but I can't get anything to work, I do not have access to modify the schema so I cannot use Stored Procedures or create temporary tables.
DECLARE
   resultItems ARRAY;
   table_names ARRAY;
   table_name STRING;
   min_date TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN
   SELECT ARRAY_AGG(TABLE_NAME) INTO table_names
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MY_SCHEMA'; 

   resultItems := ARRAY_CONSTRUCT();

   FOR i IN 1 : ARRAY_RANGE(1, ARRAY_SIZE(table_names)) LOOP
       
       table_name := table_names[i];
   
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
       'SELECT MIN(pub_date) INTO :min_date FROM MY_SCHEMA.'||table_name||';';
      
       resultItems := ARRAY_APPEND(resultItems, OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
            'table_name', table_name, 'pub_date', min_date));
   END LOOP;
   
END;

The compiler gives me very obscure error messages when changing things so I am a bit lost now.
Any help would be appreciated, and also if someone could show me how to select all the results that would be great also.

Hi - please update your question with the error message(s) that you're getting. However, it would probably be much simpler to dynamically construct a single SQL statement that UNIONs the queries against each table and just execute that single statement

FOR i IN 1 : ARRAY_RANGE(1, ARRAY_SIZE(table_names)) LOOP expects range. Second arrays are 0-based so it should rather be  FOR i IN 0 TO ARRAY_SIZE(table_names)-1 LOOP

Second: there is no need for materializing query to loop over as array and then access array elements. A much cleaner approach is to use FOR CURSOR loop. LET cur CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MY_SCHEMA'; then    FOR row IN cur LOOP

@LukaszSzozda, thanks,  Ok so if i change to FOR i IN 0 TO ARRAY_SIZE(table_names)-1 LOOP that seems to run, thanks, how can I select the values from resultItems? nothing seems to work for me. SELECT * FROM resultItems; gives this error - 002003 (42S02): Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 25 at position 3 : SQL compilation error:

@LennyD If it is a part of stored procedure then RETURN resultItems.

@LukaszSzozda, Ok it's standalone scripting I don't have access to the schema to add stored procedures SELECT :resultItems; runs without error but value is null :/

@LennyD RETURN will do for SP and block.

This should do roughly what you want:
DECLARE
    res1 RESULTSET DEFAULT (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MY_SCHEMA' );
    cur1 CURSOR FOR res1;
    sql_stmnt STRING DEFAULT '';
    res2 RESULTSET;   
BEGIN
   FOR rec in cur1 DO
      IF (sql_stmnt = '') THEN
        sql_stmnt := 'SELECT \''||rec.table_name||'\', MIN(pub_date) FROM MY_SCHEMA.'||rec.table_name;
      ELSE
          sql_stmnt := sql_stmnt||' UNION SELECT \''||rec.table_name||'\', MIN(pub_date) FROM MY_SCHEMA.'||rec.table_name;
      END IF;
   END FOR;
   
  res2 := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :sql_stmnt);
  RETURN TABLE(res2);
END;

